# Flexbox: Container with max width and full width children in react native

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I want to build a Container for my React native app. The Container should have a max-width of 1024 px and the content should be centered if the screen size is too large. Within the container I want to add a list item with full width 100% (see image):[image]

The problem is, that my List Item doesn't grow to the full 100%.  [image]

My code so far:

```
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
      <SafeAreaView
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          maxWidth: 1024,
          alignSelf: 'center',
        }}
      >
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            borderColor: 'black',
            borderWidth: 1,
            padding: 4,
            width: '100%',
          }}
        >
          <Text>I am a ListItem</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your view doesn't occupy the full width of the screen despite the fact that you are setting `width` to `100%` is the `alignSelf` style property of your parent view.

You can align the child and control the width at the same time as follows:

```js
<View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
      <SafeAreaView
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          maxWidth: 1024,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}
      >
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            borderColor: 'black',
            width: "100%",
            borderWidth: 1,
            padding: 4,
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}
        >
          <Text>I am a ListItem</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
```

If you do not want to center the child view but only the text, then remove `justifyContent` and `alignItems` from the `SafeAreaView` completely and you are done.

Comment: This stretches my List Item to 100% width, but with your code the content is not centered in the middle of a screen > 1024 px. The content sticks to the left.